# What does depth for git clone mean?

Tags: git, git-clone

We tried to speed up the CI build of one of our software projects at work. Somebody committed some huge (by git's standards) binaries early in the project's life. Rewriting git's history just to get rid of them seems like too much trouble, so we figured doing a shallow clone that avoided those big early commits would be good enough.

I did some experiments with `--depth` parameter for clone and encountered some weird behavior. This is what help for git clone says about it:

```
--depth <depth>
           Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of commits. Implies
           --single-branch unless --no-single-branch is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all
           branches. If you want to clone submodules shallowly, also pass --shallow-submodules.
```

This would indicate that `<depth>` will equal the number of commits that will be fetched during the clone, but it's not the case. This is what I got when I tried different values for depth:

```
| depth   | commit count linux repo | commit count git repo |
|---------|-------------------------|-----------------------|
| 1       | 1                       | 1                     |
| 5       | 15                      | 13                    |
| 10      | 80                      | 46                    |
| 100     | 93133                   | 39552                 |
| 1000    | 788718                  | 53880                 |
```

For cloning I used this command `git clone --depth 10 https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git`, `git clone --depth 100 https://github.com/git/git.git`, and for counting the commits I used this `git log --oneline | wc -l`. (At work I observed the same thing with a GitLab server, so it can't be an artifact of how GitHub works.)

Does anybody know what is going on? How does the value for depth correspond to the actual amount of data downloaded? Do I understand the documentation wrongly, or is there a bug?

EDIT: I added results for a second repo

Comment: I imagine that merge commits could affect what you're seeing.

Comment: BTW if you have this issue again try: `git clone --filter=blob:none <url>` this will get you everything (i.e. you can do `git fetch` on it later) without those huge files.

Comment: @Ariel That's pretty cool. I didn't know this existed. BTW the `--filter` was introduced in [git 2.27.0](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone/2.27.0#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As [Jonathon Reinhart commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683896/what-does-depth-for-git-clone-mean#comment94224569_53683896), you're seeing the effect of merges.

The `--depth` parameter refers to how deep Git goes on a "walk" from each starting point.  As the documentation you quoted mentions, it also implies `--single-branch`, which simplifies talking about this.  The important point here is that the walk visits *all* parents of each commit, which—for each depth level—is more than one commit if the commit itself is a merge.

Suppose we have a commit graph that looks like this:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline master
* cf68824 profile: fix PATH with GOPATH
* 7c2376b profile: add Ruby gem support
* 95c8270 profile: set GOPATH
* 26a9cc3 vimrc: fiddle with netrw directory display
* 80b88a5 add ruby gems directory to path
[snip]
```

Here, each commit has just one parent.  If we use `--depth 3` we'll pick up the tip commit `cf68824`, its parent `7c2376b` at depth 2, and finally `95c8270` at depth 3—and then we stop, with three commits.

With the Git repository for Git, however:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline master
*   965798d1f2 Merge branch 'es/format-patch-range-diff-fix-fix'
|\  
| * ac0edf1f46 range-diff: always pass at least minimal diff options
* |   5335669531 Merge branch 'en/rebase-consistency'
|\ \  
| * | 6fcbad87d4 rebase docs: fix incorrect format of the section Behavioral Differences
* | | 7e75a63d74 RelNotes 2.20: drop spurious double quote
* | | 7a49e44465 RelNotes 2.20: clarify sentence
[snip]
```

With `--depth 3`, we start with `965798d1f2`, then—for depth 2—pick up *both* parents, `ac0edf1f46` and `5335669531`.  To add the depth-3 commits, we pick up all the parents of those two commits.  The (lone) parent of `ac0edf1f46` is not visible here, while the two parents of `5335669531` are (namely `6fcbad87d4` and `7e75a63d74`).  To get the hash IDs of the parents of `ac0edf1f46` we can use:

```
$ git rev-parse ac0edf1f46^@
d8981c3f885ceaddfec0e545b0f995b96e5ec58f
```

so that gives us our six commits: the tip of master (which is currently a merge commit), two parents of that commit, one parent of one of those parents, and two parents of the other of that parent.

Depending on precisely when you ran the clone of Git, the tip-most `master` is often not a merge, but often has a merge as its immediate parent, so that `--depth 2` will often get you 3 commits, and `--depth 3` will therefore get *at least* 5, depending on whether the two parents of the tip of `master` are themselves merges.

(Compare the above `git rev-parse` output with:

```
$ git rev-parse 965798d1f2^@
5335669531d83d7d6c905bcfca9b5f8e182dc4d4
ac0edf1f46fcf9b9f6f1156e555bdf740cd56c5f
```

for instance.  The `^@` suffix means *all parents of the commit, but not the commit itself*.)

Answer (score 22):

`--depth` means the number of commits to grab when you clone.

By default git download **all your history** of all branches.
Meaning that your copy will have to all history, so you will be able to "switch" (checkout) to any commit you wish.

Adding the `--depth` limit the size fo your clone and checkout only the X last commits

```
# Cloning a  single branch with the following:
# clone specific branch and limit the history to last X commits
git clone --branch<...> --depth=<X>
```

> How does the value for depth correspond to the actual amount of data downloaded?
> with the `--depth` git will **only** download the content corresponding to the commits in the given range so the size of the repo will raise when the value is larger

---

> This would indicate that  will equal the number of commits that will be fetched during the

**Not always, if any of those commits is a merge (for example no fast forward) you will get more than X commits.**

---

#### How to clean your binary:

> Rewriting git's history just to get rid of them seems like too much trouble

This tool can do it for you:

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner

> ###***`BFG Repo-Cleaner`***
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.

> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:

> *** Removing Crazy Big Files***
>
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

> Examples (from the official site)
> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

Comment: Not sure this really answers the OP’s question. The OP gave examples of how the depth is not what it’s expected to be. The examples the OP gave don’t match what you said about the depth command.

Comment: That's nice, but it doesn't answer the question. I know there are tools for this (I even used this tool before). But unless there is a way to do this without rewriting the history, it's a no go for me.

Comment: BTW this might be the single worst thing about git. Once you push, it's there forever. Unless you don't want people screaming at you that is... (Yes, it has happened before. OK, it was a little less dramatic :) This is a huge gotcha for git noobs. I would like a warning when you git add -A a binary that's bigger than say 100kB.

Comment: You can use git hooks to do it. GITHUB warn you for doing so for the past few years

Answer (score 2):

As others already stated, depth is not number of commits, but commits an merges.  This is similar to the `find . -maxdepth 2` which doesn't return two files, but instead returns everything in this directory and its child directories.

For more information on using --depth, see my blog post, "[Exploring Git Clone --depth](https://medium.com/@thriving_chiffon_gnu_714/exploring-git-clone-depth-828eb4bac6c4)".